# Program seemingly hanging in between main() and user defined function

Tags: c

I am having a very strange issue with my C program I am writing where the program apparently hang when I attempt to call the areAnagrams function from the main function.
The program runs up until the point at which it is asked to enter this function, and then simply never enters it. Perhaps the insight of veterans can provide some assistance?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int areAnagrams(char *word1, char *word2);
int main(void) {
    char word1[25], word2[25];
    printf("Enter first word: ");
    gets(word1);
    printf("Enter the second word: ");
    gets(word2);
    printf("%d", areAnagrams(word1, word2));
    if(areAnagrams(word1, word2) == 1){
        printf("The words are anagrams.");
    }else{
        printf("The words are not anagrams.");
    }
}

int areAnagrams(char *word1,  char *word2){
    int hash[26], i = 0;
    char curr;    
    while((curr = *(word1+i)) != '\0'){
        if(isalpha(curr) == 0){
            continue; //skip non-alphabetics
        }
        hash[(tolower(curr)-97)] += 1;
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while(curr = *(word2+i) != '\0'){
        if(isalpha(curr) == 0){
            continue; //skip non-alphabetics
        }
        hash[(tolower(curr)-97)] -= 1;
        i++;
    }

    int anaFlag = 1; //zero indicates non-anagrams
    for(i = 0; i <= 26; i++){
        if(*(hash+i) != 0){
            anaFlag = 0;
        }
    }
    return anaFlag;
}
```

Comment: hash[] is uninitialised. `while((curr = *(word1+i)) != '\0'){` is ugly style. `while((curr = word1[i] )){` would suffice. (the extra `()` are only needed to suppress silly warnings)

Answer (score 1):

The point is that your functions never *returns*.

Your loops never finish because when `isalpha() == 0` you `continue` and so the `i` is not incremented. Remember that continue jumps to the start of the loop.

You will be better with a `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; (cur= word[i]) != 0; ++i)
{
    if (...)
        continue;
}
```

Now, the `continue` will jump to the increment expression.

BTW, why the convoluted `*(word + i)` instead of `word[i]`? They are exactly the same!

PS: please, do not use `gets()`. It is deprecated. Use `fgets(stdin,...)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will try that out. As for the pointer arithmetic, I am just learning to play with pointers and so I am helping myself to know what I can and can't do with them by using them :P

Comment: Also, `hash[(tolower(curr)-97)]` might write out of bounds of the array, which could lead to strange behaviour in your program that is hard to track down. You could tidy this up with something like `unsigned int index = tolower( (unsigned char)curr ) - 'a'; if ( index < 26 ) ++hash[index];`